# How do I find the Number of ways to reach n− n, without the score having been tied before?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find out the number of ways to reach a Nth number without having the scores tied.

Example to reach 2-2 I have 2 ways to reach it without having the scores tied and 6 ways to reach it tied
0,0 > 0,1 > 0,2 > 1,2 > 2,2
0,0 > 1,0 > 2,0 > 2,1 > 2,2
Whilst
0,0 > 1,0 > 1,1 is not allowed because it is a tie

What I have already found out is that we can find the amount ways to reach a number in pascal's triangle by this sequence {n \choose r} = t(\frac{\n!}{r!(n-1)!}

What I want to know is how is the sequence related to pascal's triangle
and how we could find any Nth number

Sequence number on OEIS A284016
if it helps, I am too confused by it

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.stackexhange. Please read the MathJax tutorial, linked here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, and use it to write your formulas :).

Comment: Here's how to read the OEIS A284016 entry: it says your sequence is double another one, A000108.  So  you look there, and see that *that* sequence is the *Catalan numbers*, with a formula and a bunch of literature references.  You could now look at [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) to learn more.  Assignment: *why* is your sequence obviously the double of the Catalan numbers.